# How to load Excel from URL into a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, url

I've been trying to load an Excel sheet from URL with zero success. This is how I used to do so:

```
url= 'https://www.ins.gov.co/BoletinesCasosCOVID19Colombia/2020-08-07.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(url)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your `socket` to `ExcelFile`:

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib2
url= 'https://www.ins.gov.co/BoletinesCasosCOVID19Colombia/2020-08-07.xlsx'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)
xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
```